# Python: Program not checking full or statement

Tags: python, function

some assistance is needed:

I've been having some trouble with the OR operand ...I understand how it works ( either or condition must be true), but i'm not sure why it is behaving in the fashion explained below.

The 'or' statement doesn't seem to be checking the second condition in my "flowContol' function.. when I enter 'y' it sees the condition as true and runs without any problems... however when i enter 'yes' it evaluates the condition as false...

-I excluded the other functions-..

```
def flowControl():
    answer = input("do you want run the 'displayLession' function? ( yes or 
    no)").strip()
    if answer == ('y' or 'yes'):
        displayLesson()
else:
    userTime()
    print('End program')
```

flowControl()

Comment: 'y' or 'yes' always returns 'y'. `or` always returns the first value that is True, so you are comparing always with 'yes'

Comment: "... comparing with 'y'" I meant.

Comment: thanks for clarifying- much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is

```
if answer == 'y' or answer == 'yes':
```

Or

```
if answer in ['y', 'yes']:
```

Why? Simple, your code evaluates before what is between parentheses `'y' or 'yes'` and this is `'y'`, because `'y'` is a truthy expression in python, so no need to evaluate the latter expression.

Comment: hmm...never heard of that term "Truthy expression"..sorry for the confusion.. but is it choosing 'y' simply because it's 'y'???

Comment: An expression considered True

Comment: Something whose value is not directly True (maybe) but it evaluates to True in a boolean context, and this is a boolean context

Comment: ah i see thanks for clarifying

Comment: My pleasure Sir